# get_version can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So I am using parse.com(a backhand database provider, made by facebook) for my unity project. I got stuck with a serious problem. Here is the explanation;

as long as i throw out my **Synchronization** codes from my game everything works fine but i need it in order to make the player sync their data to the server.

So here is the error im an getting:

> get_version can only be called from the main thread.
>    Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
>    Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

And here is my user.cs code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using Parse;

public class User : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isAuthenticated = false;
    public string userName = null;
    public int level;
    public int exp;
    public int money;
    public GoLobby golobby;
    public Sync sync;
    public bool isGoLobbyEnabled = false;

public void LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Member")
            .WhereEqualTo("Username", username)
            .WhereEqualTo("Password", password);
        query.FirstOrDefaultAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                       {
            ParseObject result = t.Result;
            //print (result);
            string playerName = result.Get<string>("Username");
            string playerPassword = result.Get<string>("Password");
            int playerLevel = result.Get<int>("Level");
            int playerexp = result.Get<int>("Experience");
            int playerMoney = result.Get<int>("Money");
            isAuthenticated = true;
            userName = playerName;
            money = playerMoney;
            exp = playerexp;
            sync.SyncToServer (userName, level, exp, money);
            isGoLobbyEnabled = true;
            GoLobby();
        });
    }
```

Here is my Sync.cs code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;

public class Sync : MonoBehaviour {

    public void SyncToServer (string username, int level, int exp, int money)
    {
        var query2 = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Member")
            .WhereEqualTo ("Username", username);
        query2.FirstAsync ().ContinueWith (t =>
                                           {
            ParseObject obj = t.Result;
            Debug.Log (obj.ObjectId); //Works fine
            obj["Level"] = level;
            obj["Experience"] = exp;
            obj["Money"] = money;
            obj.SaveAsync();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post all the code. Just the code we need.

Comment: Edited the post. Deleted the unneeded content.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to Unity5 and latest parse right..?
Unity5+Old parse is not giving any issue, 
Unity5+New parse(PushNotifications) is giving Error.
We have opened issue ticket for parse SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/390409301154954